# Force asynchronous operation to block current thread

Tags: java, concurrency

I have an API that only supports asynchronously doing some operation, and I want to force it to block my thread.

```
static void doWorkSync(Worker worker) {
  final Condition condition = new ReentrantLock().newCondition();
  worker.doWorkAsync(() -> condition.signal());
  try {
    condition.await();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e);
  }
}
```

Are Conditions, as used above, the sanest solution for this case?

Comment: What does the `doWorkAsync` API look like? `void` with something like a `Runnable` callback parameter?

Comment: Also, you can't `signal` or `await` without owning the corresponding `Lock`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes: `void doWorkAsync(Runnable action)`

Comment: The sanest solution is likely `CountDownLatch`. Just initialize it with a count of 1, then `countDown` in the callback (though make sure the callback is actually invoked in the `doWorkAsync`'s implementation, on success and failure). Finally `await` for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) is what you're looking for!

```
static void doWorkSync(Worker worker) {
  final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
  worker.doWorkAsync(() -> latch.countDown());
  try {
    latch.await();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new AssertionError(e);
  }
}
```